# Help with asp.net mvc select dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, select, drop-down-menu

I have a marital status field in my users table that its just varchar
yet I only want to give the users four options (married, single, widowed and divorced) and i want to have the correct one selected when Im editing the form.. is it possible? please help.

Comment: Of course it is possible.  Can you show us what you have that is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should point you in the right direction:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("listName", new string[] { "Married", "Single", "Widowed", "Divorced" }
.Select(m => new SelectListItem(){
    Selected = model.MaritalStatus == m,
    Text = m,
    Value = m
})); %>
```

Assuming that your model has a 'MaritalStatus' field,

```
Selected = model.MaritalStatus == m
```

will select the status of your model by default.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post should lead you in the right direction:

http://weblogs.asp.net/ashicmahtab/archive/2009/03/27/asp-net-mvc-html-dropdownlist-and-selected-value.aspx

you'd have to give us a little more information and maybe a code sample of what you have so far to get a more specific answer.